# Почему выполняется JS код многократно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код у меня получился рабочий, но меня смущает то, что в консоле выполняется многократное действия:

При разрежении экрана больше 768 пикселей плагин инициализируется, если меньше 768 пикселей то код не выполняется (дестрой):

```
const searchLeftContent = $(".search-left-content");

(checkAndRepaint)();
window.onresize = checkAndRepaint;

function checkAndRepaint() {

    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {

        // Инициализация плагина
        searchLeftContent.mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "dark-3"
        });

        console.log('Initial');
    } else {
        // Дестрой плагина
        searchLeftContent.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
        console.log('destroy');
    }
}
```

Я специально поместил код console.log('Initial'); что бы было ясно сколько раз выполняется действия скрипта - http://joxi.ru/V2Ve6qVfyv9Ymv
меня смущают цифры, они возникают тогда когда я меняю размер окна браузера.
Подскажите правильно ли написан скрипт?

PS. Тут можно посмотреть работу скрипта http://test.buyhtml.ru/result.html

Comment: onresize выполняется _в процессе_ изменения размера. Как только закончил менять размер функция перестала выполняться. Аналогично работает и scroll

Comment: То есть все норм и мне не о чем волноваться?

Comment: в принципе да, наверняка в плагине есть проверка от повторной инициализации, поэтому с твоей стороны никакой разницы в работе не должно быть

Comment: Понял. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы улучшить производительность, рекомендую вам воспользоваться функцией [`debounce`](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). Таким образом, если вы потянете окошко, то функция не будет вызвана много раз подряд и не нагрузит браузер почём зря, она выполнится один раз после того, как пройдёт 250 мс после события `resize`.

```js
const searchLeftContent = $(".search-left-content");

(checkAndRepaint)();
window.onresize = debounce(checkAndRepaint, 250);

function checkAndRepaint() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {

    // Инициализация плагина
    /*searchLeftContent.mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "dark-3"
    });*/

    console.log('Initial');
  } else {
    // Дестрой плагина
    //searchLeftContent.mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
    console.log('destroy');
  }
}

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а зачем запускать таймер, если _callNow_?

Comment: Там по твоей ссылке в комментариях указали на недостатки. Вообще, какой смысл добавлять параметр Immediate? если он true - то вызов должен быть эквивалентен прямому вызову функции, но тогда зачем вообще debounce?

Comment: *если он true - то вызов должен быть эквивалентен прямому вызову функции, но тогда зачем вообще debounce?* — если он true, то функция вызывается при ресайзе сразу же и больше не вызывается. зачем это может понадобиться *кому-то*, не могу знать.

Comment: _если он true, то функция вызывается при ресайзе сразу же и больше не вызывается._ - не уверен, что в данной реализации будет именно такое поведение

Comment: только что проверил и работает это именно так, как заявлено :-)

Comment: На самом деле все не очень хорошо :-) впустую запускается таймер, который, обработчик которого ничего не делает